# StateMachine - keep the same value for the next state

Tags: plutus, statemachines

I work with the StateMachine library, and I need to transition from state to another where the `stateValue` of the `State` is exactly the same. The problem is that when I try to do the transition, I get an error that the user has insufficient funds pointing at the thread token. I presume that the `stateValue` of a `State` already includes the thread token, but it is added one more time or something like that. In summary, I have this (simplified):

```
{-# INLINABLE transition #-}
transition :: ContractParam -> State ContractDatum -> ContractRedeemer -> Maybe (TxConstraints Void Void, State ContractDatum)
transition cParam cState cRedeemer = 
  ...

     -- This is simply what I need to transition to
     Just(mempty, State ("some updated datum") (stateValue cState))

  ...
```

To summarize, I need to keep the same `stateValue` into the next state but get insufficient funds error, so I presume I need something like `(stateValue cState) - threadToken` except the threadToken is not of type Value and I can not figure out, how to convert the thread token to `Value` or how to remove the thread token from stateValue so that I don't get the insufficient funds error.

---

Edit: The code snippet should work as is, but there was a bug. The newest plutus versions work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of plutus are you using? IIRC a problem like that was fixed in the last couple of months and maybe updating your dependencies to the latest `plutus-apps` (repository was split in two) might help already.

Comment: I am using an older plutus from time of plutus pioneer program #2. I am not sure what plutus version is that but I will try updating it.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I updated to the latest plutus-starter project, and it is working as intended!